# Cyclotomic polynomial over a finite prime field

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, field-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Irreducible factors of $X^p-1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/q \mathbb{Z})\[X\]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167486/irreducible-factors-of-xp-1-in-mathbbz-q-mathbbzx)

Let $p$ be a prime number.
Let $l$ be an odd prime number such that $l \neq p$.

Let $X^l - 1 \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$.
Since $(X^l - 1)' = lX^{l-1}$, $X^l - 1$ has no multiple irreducible factor mod $p$.
Since $X^l - 1 = (X - 1)(1 + X + ... + X^{l-1})$, $1 + X + ... + X^{l-1}$ has no multiple irreducible factor mod $p$, either.

Let $1 + X + ... + X^{l-1} \equiv f_1(X)...f_r(X)$ (mod $p$), where $f_i(X)$ is a monic irreducible polynomial mod $p$.

Let $f$ be the smallest positive integer such that $p^f \equiv 1$ (mod $l$).

My question: Can we prove that the degree of each $f_i(X)$ is $f$?

Comment: this question was answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167486/irreducible-factors-of-xp-1-in-mathbbz-q-mathbbzx

Comment: @user8268 I suppose you think about the splitting field $K$ of $1 + X + ... + X^{l-1}$ over $F = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and the Galois group $G$ of $K/F$, right?

Comment: The question is (in a sense) also answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/153429/11619) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172468/11619). In your case of prime $\ell$ it is easy to see that the ($p$-)cyclotomic cosets modulo $\ell$, other than the coset of $0$, all have the same size $f$.

Answer (score 3):

We denote by $|S|$ the number of elements of a finite set $S$.

Let $F = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $\Omega$ be the algebraic closure of $F$.
Let $\omega \neq 1$ be a root of $X^l - 1$ in $\Omega$.
Let $K$ be the unique subfield of $\Omega$ such that $|K| = p^f$.
$K$ is the set of all the roots of $X^{p^f} - X$ in $\Omega$.
$K$ is a finite extension of $F$ and $[K : F] = f$.
Let $K^* = K -$ {$0$} be the multiplicative group of $K$.
It is well known that $K^*$ is a cyclic group.
Since $|K^*| = p^f - 1$ and $l|p^f - 1$, $K^*$ has a unique cyclic subgroup of order $l$.
Hence $\omega \in K^*$.

Let $L$ be a proper subfiled of $K$.
Let $[L : F] = p^r$.
Suppose $\omega \in L$.
Then $l|p^r - 1$, i.e. $p^r \equiv 1$ (mod $l$).
Since $r < f$, this is a contradiction.
Hence $K = F(\omega)$.
Hence the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $F$ has degree $f$.
This completes the proof.