# The order of the Galois group of a cyclotomic field over a finite prime field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For what $(n,k)$ there exists a polynomial $p(x) \in F_2\[x\]$ s.t. $\deg(p)=k$ and $p$ divides $x^n-1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172468/for-what-n-k-there-exists-a-polynomial-px-in-f-2x-s-t-degp-k-an)
>   [Galoisgroup $\operatorname{Gal}(K(\mu_n) / K) \subseteq (\mathbb{Z} / (n) )^*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189681/galoisgroup-operatornamegalk-mu-n-k-subseteq-mathbbz-n)

Let $p$ be a prime number.
Let $F = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $l$ be an odd prime number such that $l \neq p$.
Let $X^l - 1 \in F[X]$.
Let $K$ be the splitting field of $X^l - 1$.
Can we determine the degree $K/F$?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174131/cyclotomic-polynomial-over-a-finite-prime-field) is a related question.

Comment: Another [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172468/11619). The question has been discussed in several other questions. Look up *cyclotomic cosets* for one (but not the only) approach.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be the smallest positive integer such that $p^f \equiv 1$ (mod $l$).
Let $\Omega$ be the algebraic closure of $F$.
Let $\omega \neq 1$ be a root of $X^l - 1$ in $\Omega$.
Then, by my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174131/cyclotomic-polynomial-over-a-finite-prime-field), the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $F$ has degree $f$. Since $F(\omega)$ is the splitting field of $X^l - 1$, The degree of $K/F$ is $f$.