# How to efficiently compute the order of a prime number mod $l$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $l$ be an odd prime number.
Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p \neq l$.
I'd like to compute efficiently the order of $p$ mod $l$ using a calculator.
For example, how can I compute efficiently the order of 2 mod 53?
Thanks in advance.

My motivation came from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174380/decomposition-of-a-prime-number-in-a-cyclotomic-field).

Comment: The order in what group exactly ?

Comment: The multiplicative group of integers mod $l$. Namely $(\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z})^*$. The order of an integer mod $l$ is standard in elementary number theory.

Comment: It is cheap in general whether $p$ is a quadratic residue of $\ell$. In this case $2$ is a NR of $53$. The order divides $52$. The only interesting possibilities are $13$, $26$, $52$. It cannot be $13$, else $2$ would be a QR. So calculate $2^{26}\pmod{53}$, or maybe $2^{27}$.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, and using Legrende's symbol, we get
$$\left(\frac{2}{53}\right)=-1$$
since $\,53\neq \pm 1\mod 8\,$ , so $\,2\,$ has a chance to be a primitive root modulo $\,53\,$

Now, and doing operations modulo $\,53\,$ , we get:
$$2^6=64=11\,\,,\,11^2=15\,\,,\,11^3=6\Longrightarrow 2^{18}=(2^6)^3=11^3=6\Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow2^{26}=2^{18}\cdot 2^8=6\cdot 11\cdot 4=-1\Longrightarrow $$
$\,2\,$ is a primitive root in $\,\left(\Bbb Z/53\Bbb Z\right)^*\,$