# Prime that splits but not completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, ramification, cyclotomic-fields

I need a prime that splits but not completely in $\mathbb{Q}/(\zeta_{20})\mathbb{Q}$. Is there any way to find one quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even do it  in the sub-extension $L= \mathbb Q (\zeta_5)$: a prime $p$ that is congruent to $4 \pmod 5$ (e.g. $19$) splits completely in the quadratic sub-extension $K= \mathbb Q(\sqrt{5})$, but not in $L$.

For a quick sketch as to why this works, please see my answer [Intuition of Prime decomposition in Galois extensions of subgroups of a cyclotomic polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429646/intuition-of-prime-decomposition-in-galois-extensions-of-subgroups-of-a-cyclotom/1431505#1431505).

Edit - any prime, the residue of which generates a (proper - but that is automatic) non-trivial subgroup of $(\mathbb Z/20)^*$, will work.