# Determining the degrees of the irreducible factors of $X^{19}-1$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I'm trying to find the degrees of the irreducible factors of $X^{19}-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$ and $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}[X]$.
I'm really struggling with how to approach this question. I did notice that $X^{19}-1=(X-1)\Phi_{19}(x)$, with $\Phi_{19}(x)$ being the 19th cyclotomic polynomial, so maybe that has something to do with finding the degrees.
I also thought of factorising $\Phi_{19}(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$ and $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}[X]$, but this seems very computation heavy and probably not the right way to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167486/irreducible-factors-of-xp-1-in-mathbbz-q-mathbbzx?rq=1) help? (It's much more generalized, and you'd have to find the degree yourself.)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305111/11619), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153471/11619) in a different guise. Anyway, you need to find the smallest exponent $\ell$ such that $7^\ell\equiv1\pmod{19}$. The point is that if an extension field contains a single root of $\Phi_{19}(X)$, it contains all of them due to $19$ being a prime.

Comment: May be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/536029/11619) is the most direct match to your questions? I have answered this question a handful of times already, so I'm not gonna add another. Sorry about blowing my own trumpet to this extent.

Comment: [Another user answering this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3631374/11619).

Answer (score 1):

Because of the primality of $19$,$\newcommand{\f}{\mathbb{F}}$
a field $K$ is the splitting field for $f:=X^{19}-1$ over $\f_7$
if and only if $K$ contains a primitive $19$-th root of unity over $\f_7$.

Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\f_7$,
and $\alpha$ be a primitive $19$-th root of unity.
We have $K=\f_{7^n}$ for some $n$ by the uniqueness of finite fields.
By Lagrange theorem,
the multiplicative order of $\alpha$ divides $|K^\times|=7^n-1$,
which translates to $19\mid 7^n-1$.
It follows that $n$ is the least positive integer solution to $7^n-1\equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ 19)$.
An easy calculation shows that $n=3$.

Since the degree of any root of $f$ must divide $[K:\f_7]=3$,
this shows that the degree of any irreducible factor of $f$ is $1$ or $3$.
Also, $f$ splits completely over $\f_{7^3}$ because $\f_{7^3}$ is the splitting field for $f$.

---

By the way, the $\f_7$-factorization of $f$ is
$$
(X + 6)  (X^{3} + 2 X + 6)  (X^{3} + 3 X^{2} + 3 X + 6)  (X^{3} + 4 X^{2} + X + 6)  (X^{3} + 4 X^{2} + 4 X + 6)  (X^{3} + 5 X^{2} + 6)  (X^{3} + 6 X^{2} + 3 X + 6)
$$
and the $\f_{7^3}$-factorization of $f$ is
$$
(X + 6)  (X + 2\alpha + 4)  (X + 2\alpha + 6)  (X + 6\alpha)  (X + \alpha^2 + 5\alpha + 3)  (X + \alpha^2 + 5\alpha + 5)  (X + 2\alpha^2 + 4\alpha)  (X + 2\alpha^2 + 6\alpha)  (X + 3\alpha^2 + \alpha + 4)  (X + 3\alpha^2 + 4\alpha + 6)  (X + 3\alpha^2 + 5\alpha + 5)  (X + 4\alpha^2 + 3)  (X + 4\alpha^2 + 3\alpha + 2)  (X + 5\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1)  (X + 5\alpha^2 + 3\alpha + 1)  (X + 5\alpha^2 + 6\alpha + 3)  (X + 6\alpha^2)  (X + 6\alpha^2 + 5)  (X + 6\alpha^2 + 3\alpha + 2),
$$
where $\alpha^3+2\alpha+6=0$.